# ...including fall/falling in love

Tags: grammar

Which of the following two sentences is grammatically correct?

> They did everything together, including fall in love.
>
> They did everything together, including falling in love.

You could also tell me why if you want.

Comment: They did everything together, including falling in love. // 'Including' is a preposition; its object is typically a noun or _ing_-form. Look at the stylised  (but perfectly grammatical) re-ordering  'Everything – including falling in love – they did together.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Seconded. Or, alternatively, and perhaps more clearly, "Falling in love is one of the many things they did together."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Examples with an infinitive after "including" can be found on Google Books: https://books.google.com/books?id=WfY5CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT171&dq=%22including+run%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihzZSk2uDXAhVJ1oMKHQNeAzsQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=%22including%20run%22&f=false, https://books.google.com/books?id=3HdGCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT37&dq=%22including+steal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq_52h2-DXAhXo6IMKHaPDAuQ4ChDoAQg2MAM#v=onepage&q=%22including%20steal%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=iWTCDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA87&dq=%22including+kill%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6zpe_2-DXAhXq6oMKHSrHDOAQ6AEITzAH#v=onepage&q=%22including%20kill%22&f=false, https://books.google.com/books?id=_5tslizvCAMC&pg=PA75&dq=%22including+burn+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz9vzl2-DXAhVH_4MKHeS_BiMQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22including%20burn%20the%22&f=false, https://books.google.com/books?id=dCNwDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT33&dq=%22including+take+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBxPX42-DXAhVizIMKHbJwBtsQ6AEIWDAI#v=onepage&q=%22including%20take%20the%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=0FHoAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA282&dq=%22including+take+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb1L6F3ODXAhVk64MKHSOnBnw4ChDoAQgvMAI#v=onepage&q=%22including%20take%20the%22&f=false, https://books.google.com/books?id=ReMjJYdo2n0C&pg=PA141&dq=%22including+take+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb1L6F3ODXAhVk64MKHSOnBnw4ChDoAQg-MAU#v=onepage&q=%22including%20take%20the%22&f=false, https://books.google.com/books?id=gBwLCYSLarsC&pg=PA176&dq=%22including+stop+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSxrOn3ODXAhXD8YMKHbseAV0Q6AEIXzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22including%20stop%20the%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=WqzT0lnKPSsC&pg=PA5&dq=%22including+break+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0q4233ODXAhWl3oMKHcSICt4Q6AEIPjAE#v=onepage&q=%22including%20break%20the%22&f=false, https://books.google.com/books?id=8y76FA0OgA8C&pg=PT17&dq=%22including+break+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0q4233ODXAhWl3oMKHcSICt4Q6AEIWzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22including%20break%20the%22&f=false, https://books.google.com/books?id=IPy0AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT283&dq=%22including+break+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilopTG3ODXAhUL3YMKHdLZB9E4ChDoAQhLMAc#v=onepage&q=%22including%20break%20the%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=NPHxAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA30&dq=%22including+break+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilopTG3ODXAhUL3YMKHdLZB9E4ChDoAQhFMAY#v=onepage&q=%22including%20break%20the%22&f=false ... Sorry for the long list of comments, but I think this construction, even if rare, is common enough to deserve some attention in an answer @EdwinAshworth

Comment: @sumelic The use of an infinitive after 'including' is probably so rare as to be best considered ungrammatical. In an admittedly cursory Google search for "including fall", I've only found false positives among the first 50 hits. Similarly for "including fall in", apart from a duplicate post, and "including run". / 'Including', if always a preposition in these cases (and I've found no grammar suggesting otherwise), licenses only the _ing_-form (I'm reasonably happy with the term 'gerund' in this case), not the infinitive.

Comment: I can't respond to se16teddy's answer over on Wordreference, but I don't agree with it. There are only 6 Google hits for "done everything including make" (though admittedly I'd hoped for more than the 1600 for "done everything including making").